# Sql Query to show minutes as HH:MM but with time datatype

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I have sql query where i am converting minutes to HH:MM format by using this query

```
declare @tempt table(col1 int)
insert into @tempt  
select 140
union all
select 35
select cast (cast((col1)/60 as varchar)   
 + ':' + RIGHT('0' + cast((col1)%60 as varchar),2) as Time) Running
  from @tempt
```

and output is

```
Running
02:20:00.0000000
00:35:00.0000000
```

But i want to show as 02:20 and 00:35 .

How do i eliminate these rest of zero's ?

Comment: give length of varchar like varchar(4) or like that.

Answer (score 0):

We can cast it like this,

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),getdate(),108)
```

replace getdate() with your datetime object

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the result in `Time` datatype, in `hh:mm:ss` format

```
declare @tempt table(col1 int)
insert into @tempt  
select 140
union all
select 35
select cast (cast((col1)/60 as varchar)   
 + ':' + RIGHT('0' + cast((col1)%60 as varchar),2) as Time(0)) Running
  from @tempt
```